# How to prevent keyboard events when timer reaches zero

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I'm developing an application which is a typing test that allows users to test their typing speed by typing a passage in a specific period of time. The problem is that users are still be able to type after that period of time. How would I stop the timer after that specific time in order to stop users from typing?

---

```
CountDownTimer cdTimer; cdTimer=new CountDownTimer(30100, 1000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {        
        timerTextView.setText(String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000) + "s");
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        playAgainButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        timerTextView.setText("0s");
    }

}.start();
```

Comment: You can cancel your timer by using cdTimer.cancel();
You can set "setEnabled(false)" in your edittextview into onFinish()

Comment: you can start new activity and display that time is over, or stop timer and disable edittext

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follow

```
CountDownTimer cdTimer; cdTimer=new CountDownTimer(30100, 1000) {

public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {        
    timerTextView.setText(String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000) + "s");
}

public void onFinish() {
    <WriteHearActivityName>.this.finish();
    startActivity(<WriteHearActivityName>.this,ResultActivity.class);
}
}.start();
```

This will solve your issue +1